# Select rows from a MySQL table where value is an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a list of IDs. I use a query to select that and then fetch it as an array (I know how to do this). Then I want to select rows from another table where the IDs are in the array fetched earlier.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd most likely want to do a `WHERE field IN (...)` type query. It's essentially the equivalent of `WHERE field=X or field=Y or field=Z or ...` for every value listed in the `IN` clause.

Given that you've got an array of IDs already, the simplest way is to build the query like this:

```
$where_in = implode(',', $ids_array);

$query = "SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE idfield IN ($where_in);";
```

The usual provisos apply - be careful about SQL injection holes, always check query results for failure, etc...

Comment: shouldn't this be `$query = "SELECT ... FROM yourtable WHERE idfield IN (".$where_in.")";` ?

Comment: No. learn basic PHP syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 3):

you can do this in one query

something like this 
`SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE table2.id IN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1 WHERE blablabla)`

Answer (score 1):

```
select value1,value2 from table2 where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid doing this and consider [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) tables. One query will fetch the matched records by IDs.

for an example

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `$values` is the array, you can use the mysql IN keyword and php implode function to construct a query

```
$sql = "SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(", ",$values) . ")";
```

implode will join the elements of the array using ", "