# Using PHP to manipulate data, transforming an SQLite database to an excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, database, excel, sqlite, data-manipulation

I have tables such as tbl_building, tbl_rooms, tbl_lighting.

Each have their tuples so that there can be many buildings, many rooms within buildings and many lighting items within rooms. This is structured by giving each of the buildings/rooms/lighting their own ID.

One of the tasks that I'm trying to achieve is to display a list of lights, for each room within each building in an excel spreadsheet.

Here is my code. It is obviously wrong but I can't get my head around outputting the data.

```
function getLights($buildingID, $d, $objPHPExcel, $status){

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Please Enter Hours Of Usage: ');
        include("setText.php");$status[2]++;

        $groupStart = $status[1].$status[2];
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Lights Used:');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Count');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'kWh/yr');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Energy Saving kWh/yr');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Saving(£)');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Cost');
            $status[1]++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Change To...');    
        $groupEnd = $status[1].$status[2];

        include("setHeadersText.php");groupFill($objPHPExcel, $groupStart, $groupEnd, "calc");
        $status[2]++;$status[1] = chr(65);

        $query = "SELECT r_id FROM tbl_roomDesc WHERE b_id = '$buildingID'";
        $result = $d->query($query);
        $rooms = array();

        array_push($rooms, 2);//echo "<br/>".$row['r_id'];



            //echo "<br/>Building:";
        /*while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 
            array_push($rooms, $row['r_id']);//echo "<br/>".$row['r_id'];
        }*/

        //echo "<br/>";
        //var_dump($rooms);

        $lightArray = array(
            "CFL",
            "CFL Equivalent Halogen 100w spot",
            "CFL Equivalent Halogen 50w spot",
            "Double d",
            "Halogen 100w spot",
            "Halogen 50w spot",
            "PL",
            "T12 Single 4ft",
            "T12 Single 5ft",
            "T12 Single 6ft",
            "T12 Single 8ft",
            "T12 Twin 4ft",
            "T12 Twin 5ft",
            "T12 Twin 6ft",
            "T12 Twin 8ft",
            "T5 Quad 2ft",
            "T5 Quad 4ft",
            "T5 Single 4ft",
            "T5 Single 5ft",
            "T5 Triple 2ft",
            "T5 Triple 4ft",
            "T5 Triple 5ft",
            "T5 Twin 2ft",
            "T5 Twin 4ft",
            "T5 Twin 5ft",
            "T8 Quad 2ft",
            "T8 Quad 4ft",
            "T8 Single 4ft",
            "T8 Single 5ft",
            "T8 Single 6ft",
            "T8 Twin 2ft",
            "T8 Twin 4ft",
            "T8 Twin 5ft",
            "T8 Twin 6ft", 
            "Tungsten 60w",
            "Other"
            );

        //echo sizeof($lightArray);

        //for each room, get quant wattage and hours of each light referenced by the room id

        echo sizeOf($rooms);
        echo "<br/>";
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($rooms);$i++){

            //set empty arrays
            $size = 36;
            $lightQuantityCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
            $lightWattageCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
            $lightHoursCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);

            //get all lighting data of particular room
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lightingData WHERE r_id = '$rooms[$i]'";
            $result2 = $d->query($query2);
            $row2= $result2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

            //for each light type in the lightarray chechk if light type from query == light type in array, if so add quantity, wattage and hours to arrays


            while($row2=$result2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){

                echo "<br/>Room ID: ".$rooms[$i]."<br/>";
                $lightID = $row2['l_id'];
                $lightType = $row2['lightType'];
                $lightQuantity = $row2['lightQuantity'];
                $lightWattage = $row2['lightWattage'];
                $lightHours = $row2['lightHours'];
                echo "Light Profile:<br/>Light ID:  ".$lightID."<br/>Light Type:  ".$lightType."<br/>Light Wattage:  ".$lightWattage."<br/>Light Hours:  ".$lightHours."<br/>";

                for($j=0; $j<sizeof($lightArray); $j++){
                    if($lightType == $lightArray[$j]){
                        echo "<br/>MATCH<br/>";
                        $lightQuantityCount[$j] = $lightQuantityCount[$j] + $lightQuantity;
                        $lightWattageCount[$j] = $lightWattage;
                        $lightHoursCount[$j] = $lightHoursCount[$j] + $lightHours;
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<br/>NO MATCH<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }

            //echo"<br/>ARRAY DUMP START:<br/>";
            //var_dump($lightQuantityCount);
            //echo"<br/>ARRAY DUMP END:<br/><br/>";

            echo "<br/>ADFSDFADFA : ".sizeof($lightQuantityCount);
            echo "<br/>ADFSDFADFA : ";

            for($k=0; $k<sizeof($lightQuantityCount); $k++){

                if($lightQuantityCount[$k] != 0){

                    echo "<br/>Light Type: ".$lightArray[$k]."<br/>";
                    echo "Light Quantity Count: ".$lightQuantityCount[$k]."<br/>";
                    echo "Wattage Count: ".$lightWattageCount[$k]."<br/>";
                    echo "Hours Count: ".$lightQuantityCount[$k]."<br/>";

                    include("setText.php");$status[2]++;

                    $groupStart = $status[1].$status[2];
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $lightArray[$k]);
                        $status[1]++;
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $lightQuantityCount[$k]);
                        $status[1]++;

                        $calc = $lightWattageCount[$k] * $lightQuantityCount[$k];
                        $calc2 = $calc / 1000;

                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $calc2);
                    $groupEnd = $status[1].$status[2];

                    include("setHeadersText.php");groupFill($objPHPExcel, $groupStart, $groupEnd, "calc");
                    $status[2]++;$status[1] = chr(65);
                }
            }
        }

return $status;
```

}

Comment for more information, thanks

Chris

Comment: I mess up somewhere within the for loops/ while loop, just want an easier way to do this. Large amount of data manipulation is starting to leave my brain in a mess. And.. as there is so much data, i've tried to a small amount of data. Thats what i'm trying now.

Comment: Sorry, but we're not going to read through a wall of code looking for the "obvious" bit.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to get help thats all, feel free to edit!

Comment: Break the code logic into manageable sections, and look through each in turn until you find where the logic doesn't match what you expect - standard debugging practise

Comment: See the code below, it now works, after going through the code, just needed to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved after spending a few more hours (head in code), I have managed to overcome the confusion of manipulating the data I had stored in the database.My problem that I was jumping in with too many for loops, I should of made a concrete strategy before jumping in.

So the code below takes a building, its rooms and makes a running total of all lights within the rooms of the building. I hope this can be of some use to people who are having problems with databases and extracting/ manipulating the data into other formats such as excel. This is what stack overflow is for right. Here is the code:

```
//prints list of lights used in building with kwh/year and savings
```

function getLights($buildingID, $d, $objPHPExcel, $status){

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Lighting Information: ');
include("setText.php");$status[2]++;

$groupStart = $status[1].$status[2];
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Lights Used');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Count');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'kWh/yr');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Energy Saving kWh/yr');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Saving(£)');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Cost');
    $status[1]++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], 'Change To...');    
$groupEnd = $status[1].$status[2];

include("setHeadersText.php");groupFill($objPHPExcel, $groupStart, $groupEnd, "calc");
$status[2]++;$status[1] = chr(65);

$query = "SELECT r_id FROM tbl_roomDesc WHERE b_id = '$buildingID'";
$result = $d->query($query);
$rooms = array();

while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 
    array_push($rooms, $row['r_id']);
}

$lightArray = array(
"CFL",
"CFL Equivalent Halogen 100w spot",
"CFL Equivalent Halogen 50w spot",
"Double d",
"Halogen 100w spot",
"Halogen 50w spot",
"PL",
"T12 Single 4ft",
"T12 Single 5ft",
"T12 Single 6ft",
"T12 Single 8ft",
"T12 Twin 4ft",
"T12 Twin 5ft",
"T12 Twin 6ft",
"T12 Twin 8ft",
"T5 Quad 2ft",
"T5 Quad 4ft",
"T5 Single 4ft",
"T5 Single 5ft",
"T5 Triple 2ft",
"T5 Triple 4ft",
"T5 Triple 5ft",
"T5 Twin 2ft",
"T5 Twin 4ft",
"T5 Twin 5ft",
"T8 Quad 2ft",
"T8 Quad 4ft",
"T8 Single 4ft",
"T8 Single 5ft",
"T8 Single 6ft",
"T8 Twin 2ft",
"T8 Twin 4ft",
"T8 Twin 5ft",
"T8 Twin 6ft", 
"Tungsten 60w",
"Other"
);

$size = 36;
$lightQuantityCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
$lightWattageCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
$lightHoursCount = array_fill(0, $size, 0);

    $id_nums = implode(", ", $rooms);

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lightingData WHERE r_id IN ($id_nums)";
    $result2 = $d->query($query2);

    while($row2=$result2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){

        $lightID = $row2['l_id'];
        $roomID = $row2['r_id'];
        $lightType = $row2['lightType'];
        $lightQuantity = $row2['lightQuantity'];
        $lightWattage = $row2['lightWattage'];
        $lightHours = $row2['lightHours'];

    for($a=0; $a<sizeOf($lightArray); $a++){

        if($lightType == $lightArray[$a]){
            $lightQuantityCount[$a] = $lightQuantityCount[$a] + $lightQuantity;
            $lightWattageCount[$a] = $lightWattage;
            $lightHoursCount[$a] = $lightHours;
        }
    }
}

for($b=0; $b<sizeOf($lightArray); $b++){

    $groupStart = $status[1].$status[2];
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $lightArray[$b]);
        $status[1]++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $lightQuantityCount[$b]);
        $status[1]++;

        $calc = $lightWattageCount[$b] * $lightQuantityCount[$b];
        $calc2 = $calc / 1000;

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($status[1].$status[2], $calc2);
    $groupEnd = $status[1].$status[2];

    $status[2]++;$status[1] = chr(65);
}

return $status;
```

}

Useful links:

Imploding an array to form a query within sql: [Imploding an array to use as a sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468204/select-rows-from-a-mysql-table-where-value-is-an-array)

PHP Excel, perfect for PHP->EXCEL transformation:

[Link to PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

And Good old trust arrays from the php manual:

[ARRAY manual PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Here is an image of the output of my code:

[image: image of output of the code above]

Any questions regarding this question, comment!